# how to add search result on top of other views

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` in my layout which is used to get the search query from the user. I want to show a `LinearLayout` bellow it when user enters some characters and fill it with the results (This layout should appear after entering at least N characters). But I don't know how to show this layout? 
I thought of putting the whole layout shown in the activity inside a `FrameLayout` and add the view when required, but there will be two problems:

1. The view will be added on the top left of the screen.
2. If I want to move it with adding some padding to it, all the area will correspond to the click event.

To explain what I want more, please take a look at this:

[image]

Comment: Use AutoCompleteTextview instead of EditText

Comment: @Aashvi Does it have such an ability? Can I extend it or anyway use my custom Layout for the results part?

Comment: check my answer i posted image with it. I think you need quite same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this link will help you, you need to use AutoCompleteTextVIew

http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example
https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your hint was enough indeed, and thank you for the reference. I guess this is a good one too, in case you want more advanced results as I do. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

These is two approaches for your case.

- Use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm)
- Use [android-popupwindow](/questions/tagged/android-popupwindow).

The former is easier and more acceptable, however if your want to customize the layout of the resulting search, for example arranging them in a gird view, you may what to use the latter option.

Although, `AutoCompleteTextView` internally uses the latter option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to another option, but I think you can customize `AutoCompleteTextView` as well, as I mentioned in my comment under the accepted answer.